# How to add a check box to Vuetable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-tables-2

I created a table using "vue table 2", but couldn't add checkbox to that.

I tried to '__checkbox' option refer to the link below
https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-tutorial/wiki/lesson-11#__checkbox

```
var apps = [
    {
        appId: 1,
        name: 'sample1'
    },
    {
        appId: 2,
        name: 'sample2'
    },
    {
        appId: 3,
        name: 'sample3'
    },
    // .... //
];

var table = $('<div id="vue-sample"><v-client-table :columns="columns" :data="data" :options="options"></v-client-table></div>');
new Vue({
    el: "#vue-sample",
    data: {
        columns: [
            'appId',
            'name',
        ],
        data: apps,
        options: {
            headings: {
                appId: 'AppId',
                name: 'AppName',
            },
            sortable: [
                // 'appId', 'name'
            ],
            texts: {
                filterPlaceholder: 'serch window'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

thanks.